# How to calculate the nth derivative of $x^2(1+x)^n$ using Leibniz's method?

Tags: derivatives

I decomposed the function $$f(x)=x^2(1+x)^n$$ to two functions to $$u(x)=x^2$$ and $$v(x)=(1+x)^n$$

Comment: Have you tried to apply the [Leibniz formula](https://www.math24.net/leibniz-formula/)? What part are you stuck at?

Comment: The expression of the nth derivative of $$v(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

From the Leibniz formula,
$$(uv)^{(n)} = \sum_{i = 0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\i\end{pmatrix}u^{(n - i)}v^{(i)}.$$

For $v(x) = (1 + x)^n$, $v'(x) = n(1 + x)^{n - 1}, v''(x) = n(n-1)(1 + x)^{n - 2}$ and so on. Can you find $v^{(n)}(x)$?

Comment: I'm actually confused between the polynomial's power which is n and the nth derivative.

Comment: is it just $$n!$$, and I'm overthinking it too much?

Comment: $n!$ is correct.

Comment: $$v^{(n)} = n\cdot(n - 1)\cdot(n - 2)\cdots2\cdot1\cdot(1 + x)^{n - n} = n!\cdot(1 + x)^0 = n!\cdot1 = n!$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You shouldn't use the same letter to denote two different things. So I'll denote
$\;f(x)=x^2(1-x)^r$.

Now Leibniz' formula asserts that
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \bigl(x^2\bigr)^{(k)}\bigl((1+x)^r \bigr)^{(n-k)}$$
and you can observe that $\;\bigl(x^2\bigr)^{(k)}=0\,$ if $\,k>2$, $\:\:\bigl((1+x)^r \bigr)^{(n-k)}=0\,$ if $\,n-k>r$.

Comment: It was given yesterday in my test, it confused me, soI just wanted to make sure

Comment: In  the end, after you've simplified the general formula you obtain, you *can*  set $r=n$

Comment: Yeah, great way. Tbf, I did the same thing you did with w instead of r, but I got confused later and skipped the exercice because it wasn't worth wasting time on a low-mark exercise given that I still have another whole 10-point exercise to finish within less than an hour

Comment: I understand your point of view. However, it is worth ending the exercise at home – there are  quite some simplifications to be done from the gross formula.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2(1+x)^n$ is a polynomial with degree $n+2$, so its $n$-th derivative is a quadratic polynomial which depends only on the leading terms of $x^2(1+x)^n$. Since 
$$ x^2(1+x)^n = x^2\cdot\left(x^n+nx^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^{n-2}+\ldots\right) = x^{n+2}+n x^{n+1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^n+\ldots $$
we have
$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^2(1+x)^n = \frac{(n+2)!}{2}x^2 + n(n+1)!x+\frac{n(n-1)n!}{2}=\frac{n!}{2}\left[(n+2)(n+1)x^2+2n(n+1)x+n(n-1)\right].$$